# PHP: Undefined property: stdClass::$images

Tags: php, class, laravel, properties, laravel-blade

below is a var_dump from a foreach

[image]

and my blade where i get the error

[image]

so when i use `{{ $watcher->images->avatar->full }}` i get a `Undefined property: stdClass::$images` error but the property is there ?

what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: According to that screenshot, it should work. Maybe it isn't defined in every `$watcher` element but only some of them?

Comment: @AlexandreLeprêtre you are right https://yadi.sk/i/u0-957dHjUc5m thank you, now it works like this `{{ $watcher->images->avatar->full or '' }}`